# Django: delete auxiliary annotation from queryset

Tags: django, django-models

I am building a complicated queryset over a complicated datamodel.
The queryset must return a selection of model objects `A` with an annotation `ann`.

For computing `ann`, I need an auxiliary annotation `aux`, but no `aux` is allowed to exist in the final results of the queryset.

```
qs = A.objects.filter(...)  # complicated
qs = qs.annotate(aux=...)  # complicated
qs = qs.annotate(ann=Case(
    When(condition=Q(aux=0), 
         then Value('some')),
    When(condition=Q(aux_gt=0),
         then Value('other'))))
```

How to return `qs` with `ann` but without `aux`?

(Alternatively: If `aux` is a count and `ann` discriminates zero and non-zero `aux`, is there
a better way to approach the whole problem?)

Answer (score 11):

Django 3.2 introduced a feature to solve specifically this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#alias

`alias()` works like `annotate()` except only for other queryset methods such as `annotate()`: it doesn't stay in the final output.

```
qs = A.objects.filter(...)
qs = qs.alias(aux=...)  # using alias here instead of annotate
qs = qs.annotate(ann=Case(
When(condition=Q(aux=0), 
     then Value('some')),
When(condition=Q(aux_gt=0),
     then Value('other'))))
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ugly hack:

A simple, if highly unelegant method is to rename `aux` to be called `ann` as well.
That way, the second annotation overwrites the first and the first will no longer exist in the output.

```
qs = A.objects.filter(...)  # complicated
qs = qs.annotate(ann=...)  # complicated
qs = qs.annotate(ann=Case(
    When(condition=Q(ann=0), 
         then Value('some')),
    When(condition=Q(ann_gt=0),
         then Value('other'))))
```

This appears to work.
Tested with Django 1.11 on SQlite and PostgreSQL.

But there must be a better way, pleeeease.

Comment: why not use `values`? and how the extra field break your code?

Answer (score 1):

It's not documented, but there is `QuerySet().query.annotations` dictionary which you can manipulate to remove annotations from the results:

```py
qs = A.objects.filter(...)  # complicated
qs = qs.annotate(aux=...)  # complicated
qs = qs.annotate(ann=Case(
    When(condition=Q(aux=0), 
         then Value('some')),
    When(condition=Q(aux_gt=0),
         then Value('other'))))

qs.query.annotations.pop('aux')
```

It works both for "auxilary annotations" that you mentioned and for filtering. E.g. you can remove all the annotations in the end if you just wanted to filter things on them:

```py
qs = A.objects.filter(...)  # complicated
qs = qs.annotate(aux=...)  # complicated
qs = qs.annotate(ann=Case(
    When(condition=Q(aux=0), 
         then Value('some')),
    When(condition=Q(aux_gt=0),
         then Value('other'))))
qs = qs.filter(ann='some')
qs.query.annotations.pop('aux', None).pop('ann', None)
```

But if you can afford to use newer django (3.2+), then just use `qs.alias()` as suggested in another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69486332/952437